# Error Date format Picture Ends Before Converting Entire Input String

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Oracle I'm getting the error:

> Error Date format Picture Ends Before Converting Entire Input String

when I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (trunc(sysdate) - to_date (completion_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'))>0
```

The completion_date field is in varchar and its value is `2018-11-30 00:00:00.723000`

Comment: Why on earth do you store date/time values as string?

Answer (score 1):

The value stored as varchar is a TIMESTAMP, not a DATE.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' ;
Session altered 

SQL>  select to_timestamp('2018-11-30 00:00:00.723000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-11-3000:00:00.723000','YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
30-NOV-18 12.00.00.723000000 AM
```

If you want a date

```
SQL> select to_date(to_char(to_timestamp('2018-11-30 00:00:00.723000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) from dual;

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_
-------------------
2018-11-30 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Comment: Converting a `string -> timestamp -> string -> date` is useless. Better use `cast(to_timestamp('2018-11-30 00:00:00.723000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') as date)`. Your query will only work if your current session parameter is `NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`

Comment: better is not the same as useless. I should try to be more polite. I was providing an example for delivering a date from a varchar2 in timestamp format, if under your opinion is not the better option, perfect, but saying useless to something which works?? useless would be something that does not work at all.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker and I didn't want to be rude - sorry. However, your proposal works only under condition I stated in my comment.

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit, no problem at all. For sure it will only work in that condition, as the input data stored on the table provided as example is stored that way. I edited my answer to put that actually I was changing my nls parameter date session

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the first 10 characters of the string and proceed as follows:

```
to_Date(SUBSTR(completion_date,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

please use below statement
`select * from TABLE where (trunc(sysdate) - to_date(substr(completion_date,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD'))>0`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Most answers will benefit from an explanation to help visitors hone in on the important elements of your solution. Explanations increase long term value allowing uture visitors to learn from & apply your knowledge to their own code, keeps quality of SO high, & encourages the use of SO platform as a knowledge base, rather than a "give me the code" or, free coding service. Eplanations are usually quicker to digest/understand than strictly interpreting code, & helps distinguish your solution with other solutions. Well crafted answers are more often upvoted